# Doctrine entity error

Tags: doctrine, entity

I am getting this error from Doctrine:

`The mappings X\Answer#question and X\Question#answers are inconsistent with each other.`

I don't see what is wrong with it?

The classes are:

Answer:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="question_id")
 */
private $question;
```

Question:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="item")
 */
protected $answers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mappedBy="item"` needed to be `mappedBy="question"`.